# A local PID is a Euclidean domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Studying commutative algebra I've encountered this statement:

> A PID which is also a local ring is a Euclidean domain.

Is it true ? Why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A local PID is a discrete valuation ring (or a field). Use that valuation to define the Euclidean norm.